# Is it safe to keep /data partition when switching from one ROM to another?

Tags: data-transfer

If I am switching from stock/custom ROM to custom/stock ROM, would it be safe to keep the /data partition so as to keep the data there as it is?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no.  It's always a good idea to do a wipe when switching ROMs so as to prevent any issues due to incompatible data.

You should back up things like games and save data individually, or use the backup through your Google account where available.

Comment: Even if I have the same Android version on both the ROMs?

Comment: @HarshitGarg Yes.

Comment: @HarshitGarg You'd want both the same Android version and the same kind of ROM -- such as a very minor update from the manufacturer to the stock ROM.